# HasValue() or ?? operand when dealing with nullable types in LINQ-to-Entity,

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have had the following code to assign a value to nullable int variable:

```
ParentCommentId = lac.ParentCommentId ?? lac.ParentCommentId.Value,
```

However, with this code I was receiving the `Nullable object must have a value` error.

Then, I revised the code as follows:

```
ParentCommentId = lac.ParentCommentId.HasValue ? lac.ParentCommentId.Value : null,
```

And, now everything works fine. I wonder why `??` operand does not work in this case. Am I using it wrong? In what cases, `??` would be more suitable?

Comment: Why not simply `ParentCommentId = lac.ParentCommentId`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Nullable object must have a value` is a runtime exception that occurs when you try to access `.Value` of a nullable with `.HasValue` false.

Your code:

```
ParentCommentId = lac.ParentCommentId ?? lac.ParentCommentId.Value
```

gets translated to:

```
if (lac.ParentCommentId.HasValue)
{
    ParentCommentId = lac.ParentCommentId.Value;
}
else
{
    ParentCommentId = lac.ParentCommentId.Value;
}
```

As you can see, both branches are doing the same and you would be accessing `.Value` even if `HasValue` is false (and will result in that exception).

The operator `??` is used to take the first not-null value. You can write

```
var value = value1 ?? value2 ?? value3;
```

The first of `value1`, `value2`, `value3` that is not `null` will be assigned to `value`, if all are `null` then `value` will be set to `null`.

Answer (score 2):

> `ParentCommentId = lac.ParentCommentId ?? lac.ParentCommentId.Value,`
> I wonder why ?? operand does not work in this case.

When you use the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) `??` it's shorthand for a short set of steps, the steps in a general sense do the following

1. Is `lac.ParentCommentId` something that can be `null`?
   Yes -> Continue
   No  -> Give a compiler error saying you can't use the `??` operator on something that can't be null because it's the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator).
2. Is `lac.ParentCommentId` `null`?
   Yes -> Continue
   No  -> Set the value of `ParentCommentId` to the value of `lac.ParentCommentId`, if they're the same type.
3. Set the value of `ParentCommentId` to the value of `lac.ParentCommentId.Value`, if they're the same type.

When you break down what the `??` operator does you can see that it runs into a problem right around step 2.

What you **want** is when `lac.ParentCommentId` has a value, to set `ParentCommentId` to `lac.ParentCommentId.Value`.

However, when you use the `??` that's not what you're doing. Instead it looks like you're saying 'When `lac.ParentCommentId` has a value, set `ParentCommentId` to `lac.ParentCommentId`'.

There is a way we can work around this, and it's actually pretty simple, because `lac.ParentCommentId` is already a nullable value we can simply use

```cs
ParentCommentId = lac.ParentCommentId ?? AlternativeValue
```

If we also consider that `null` is an acceptale value for `ParentCommentId`, we can actually simplify this even more for a more elegant solution and use:

```cs
ParentCommentId = lac.ParentCommentId
```

**Edit:** the following only applies to LINQ-to-Objects and **not** entity-framework. It remains as additional information on the `?` null coelescing operator. Thanks to [Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) for pointing that out!

If the `lac.ParentCommentId.Value` is a null-able value you could instead use this:

```cs
ParentCommentId = lac?.ParentCommentId.Value ?? AlternativeValue,
```

What that does is it checks to see if **ANY** of `lac` `ParentCommentId` OR `Value` are null, and if **ANY** of them are `null`, use the alternative value.

Comment: The first part (explanation of the issue) is ok. But both workarounds are not.  null coalescing operator `?.` is not supported in expression trees, so `lac?.ParentCommentId.Value` is simply compile time error. The correct option is `lac.ParentCommentId ?? AlternativeValue`. The second "workaround" expression `lac.ParentCommentId.HasValue ? lac.ParentCommentId.Value : null` just makes no sense, since it is the exact equivalent of `lac.ParentCommentId`

Comment: Yup you're totally right! I wrote the example solutions, misunderstanding that this wasn't for LINQ-to-Object, even though *the post is literally tagged with entity-framework*! Thanks, I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: thank for the detailed explanation my friend, very much appreciated!